# Disable y-axis auto-fit in chart.js

Tags: web, charts, chart.js, linegraph, yaxis

Good morning everyone, I am working with Chart.js, I have a need to get a line chart that does not auto-fit the y-axis.
That is, I want that whatever value is loaded on the chart, the y-axis **remains visible from value 0 to value 409**. So that it does not auto-fit based on the min or max value present in the graph at that time. Basically I am fishing values every second from a database and plotting them. I've tried searching online or in the official documentation but I haven't found anything except to set min and max, or other parameters to rather facilitate the auto-fit.
Could you help me out? thanks!

Comment: Why don't you set a max, that sound exactly what you want and need?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's not enough for me to set a maximum because in each case (I show 50 measurements, and every second one is added to the top and one is taken off the tail) if there is no maximum value in the 50 measurements I show, the y-axis does an autofit by zooming in between just the displayed values.

Comment: If you set a min and max the chart does not zoom, if it happens please provide a reproducible sample so people can see what you do wrong